# Boa biblioteca gráfica para iniciantes?

Tags: c

Boas, eu sei que no stackoverflow não devo entrar muito no subjectivo quando se trata de perguntas, por isso, gostaria que respondessem tendo em conta fatos e não  baseado na vossa experiencia.

Bem eu gostaria de começar a aprender a utilizar uma biblioteca gráfica. O problema é que há tantas e quando procuro tutoriais para certas como OpenGL ou SDL muitas vezes ou estão desatualizadas ou usam versões mais antigas.

Será que alguém me poderá indicar alguma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiramente devo começar por **distinguir** bibliotecas gráficas de outras bibliotecas que para além da parte gráfica também trabalham com audio, input, network, etc..

Existem diversas bibliotecas gráficas mas as mais conhecidas são **OpenGL** e **Direct3D**, lembrando que o Direct3D faz parte da **API DirectX**.

Já as outras bibliotecas (SFML, SDL, Allegro, etc..) são bibliotecas direcionadas para a área *Game Development*, pois estas para além de usar uma biblioteca gráfica (**OpenGL na maioria dos casos**) também permitem a manipulação de inputs, audio, newtork, threads, etc...

---

**Não existe uma melhor que outra**, cada uma tem os seus **aspetos positivos** e **negativos** e acho que é mau utilizarmos uma biblioteca gráfica por ela ser boa para iniciantes e/ou por alguém dizer que achou fácil.

Devemos ser nós a **avaliar a nossa decisão** e escolher uma biblioteca que enquadre nos nossos **gostos e requisitos**. 
Dito isto, **eu não vou recomendar nenhuma biblioteca**. No entanto, para aprenderes a utilizar certas bibliotecas gráficas o que poderás fazer é o seguinte:

- **Ver vídeos no YouTube.**
- **Ler livros relacionados com a biblioteca escolhida.**

Lembrando que, **maior parte das vezes este tipo de conteúdo encontra-se disponível em inglês**, então se isso for uma dificuldade para ti será um problema a enfrentar.

---

**Para finalizar,** deixo aqui alguns links referentes a tutoriais e livros, lembrando novamente que eles estão apenas disponíveis em inglês.

- [Livros para a biblioteca SFML](http://it-ebooks.info/search/?q=sfml&type=title)
- [Livros para a biblioteca SDL](http://it-ebooks.info/search/?q=sdl&type=title)
- [Livros para a biblioteca OpenGL](http://it-ebooks.info/search/?q=OpenGL&type=title)
- [Site com tutorias do DirectX](http://www.directxtutorial.com/)
- [Outro site com tutoriais do DirectX, também inclui OpenGL](http://www.rastertek.com/tutindex.html)

Poderás procurar no **YouTube** outros tutoriais, cabe a ti escolher, apenas apresentei uma pequena lista de possíveis livros que possas gostar.

Comment: Obrigado  pelas referencias ;). Só tem um problema, os livros de SDL  são direcionados para C++. Eu sei que posso adaptar a C, mas o problema é que exitem algumas especifidades como `virtual`. Como devo proceder nesses casos?

Comment: Penso que nesse tipo de casos seria melhor aprenderes C++, contudo deixo-te aqui um [site](http://www.eventhelix.com/RealtimeMantra/basics/ComparingCPPAndCPerformance2.htm#.VZByehtViko) que fala sobre as diferenças de C e C++, inclusive existe a utilização de um `virtual* no código e o tópico é _Game Development_

Comment: Boa tarde RebeloX, notei que você tem colaborado bastante e sempre com ótimas resposta, porém note que antes de responder algumas perguntas seria legal dar uma olhada no que faz parte do escopo do site pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . Fazer um comentário pode ajudar, mas formular uma resposta pode incentivar a ter muitas perguntas que não fazem parte do escopo do site e quando o autor da pergunta tiver sua questão vai se sentir frustado, devido antes ele conseguir resposta para algo offtopic e depois não conseguir mais.

Comment: Boa noite @GuilhermeNascimento, desde já obrigado pelo elogio e pela critica, de facto não tinha reparado nisso e compreendo o teu ponto de vista, apenas respondi por ser uma área a qual tenho interesse e conhecimento, levando a que acabasse por não respeitar o escopo do site, dito isto passarei a ter mais cuidado neste tipo de questões.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL e Direct3D só são necessárias se você quiser trabalhar com 3D. Em C (Assim como C++), as mais populares são [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) e [Allegro](https://www.allegro.cc/) (Que estão em suas novas versões atualmente, com suporte a [hardware acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_acceleration), multiplas janelas, etc).

Allegro possui um fórum ativo e um site oficial que te permite divulgar seus jogos ali (Porém, ambas são bibliotecas genéricas de multimídia, então é possível desenvolver o que você quiser (Um player de áudio e vídeo, por exemplo)).

Tanto o Allegro quanto a SDL possuem bindings para OpenGL e Direct3D, então é possível trabalhar em 3D com ambas (Estas bibliotecas não são apenas "gráficas", elas te permitem trabalhar com eventos / input).

Você pode utilizar o [DirectX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj554502.aspx) da Microsoft também (Porém, esta não é para "iniciantes". SDL e Allegro certamente são as recomendadas).

Comment: Já me decidi e acho que vou pelo SDL, obrigado pela resposta ;)

Comment: De nada :). Já usei os dois. Procure pelo Allegro 5, ou SDL 2.0 (Que são as novas). Eu troquei o SDL pelo Allegro porque achei a documentação mais organizada, achei a comunidade maior, e achei mais simpática a API de maneira geral (Você perguntou, "para iniciantes", então, nesse aspecto, diria que o Allegro é mais simples de se trabalhar). 

De qualquer forma, [recomendo muito este vídeo aqui, da Rachel Morris, que compara as versões atuais da SDL, Allegro e SFML](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fbmiSm8G7w). Recomendo muito o canal dela também.